# Is this text training with skip-gram correct?

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec

I am still a beginner with neural networks and NLP. 
In this code I'm training cleaned text (some tweets) with skip-gram.
But I do not know if I do it correctly.
Can anyone inform me about the correctness of this skip-gram text training? 
Any help is appreciated.

**This my code :**

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

from gensim.models.phrases import Phrases, Phraser

sent = [row.split() for row in X['clean_text']]

phrases = Phrases(sent, max_vocab_size = 50, progress_per=10000)

bigram = Phraser(phrases)

sentences = bigram[sent]

from gensim.models import Word2Vec

w2v_model = Word2Vec(window=5,
                     size = 300,
                     sg=1)

w2v_model.build_vocab(sentences)


w2v_model.train(sentences, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=25)


del sentences #to reduce memory usage


def get_mat(model, corpus, size):

    vecs = np.zeros((len(corpus), size))

    n = 0

    for i in corpus.index:
        vecs[i] = np.zeros(size).reshape((1, size))
        for word in str(corpus.iloc[i,0]).split():
            try:
                vecs[i] += model[word]
                #n += 1
            except KeyError:
                continue

    return vecs

X_sg = get_vectors(w2v_model, X, 300)

del X

X_sg=pd.DataFrame(X_sg)
X_sg.head()
from sklearn import preprocessing
scale = preprocessing.normalize
X_sg=scale(X_sg)

for i in range(len(X_sg)):
    X_sg[i]+=1 #I did this because some weights where negative! So could not 
               #apply LSTM on them later
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned if you've received any errors, or unsatisfactory results, so it's hard to know what kind of help you might need.

Your specific lines of code involving the `Word2Vec` model are roughly correct: plausibly-useful parameters (if you have a dataset large enough to train 300-dimensional vectors), and the proper steps. So the real proof would be whether your results are acceptable.

Regarding your attempted use of `Phrases` bigram-creation beforehand:

- You should get things generally working and with promising results before adding this extra pre-processing complexity.
- The parameter `max_vocab_size=50` is seriously misguided and may make the phrases-step pointless. The `max_vocab_size` is a hard cap on how many words/bigrams are tallied by the class, as a way to cap its memory-usage. (Whenever the number of known words/bigrams hits this cap, many lower-frequency words/bigrams are pruned – in practice, a majority of all words/bigrams each pruning, giving up a lot of accuracy in return for capped memory usage.) The `max_vocab_size` default in `gensim` is 40,000,000 – but the default in the Google `word2phrase.c` source on which gensim's method is based was 500,000,000. By using just `50`, it's not really going to learn anything useful about just whatever 50 words/bigrams survive the many prunings.

Regarding your `get_mat()` function & later `DataFrame` code, i have no idea what you're trying to do with it, so can't offer any opinion on it.